# Separating strings into chunks with, then passing those chunks to a new object. Python 3

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I am trying to manipulate a list of `strings` such that each string is broken up into chunks and those chunks are then stored in a new list.

Example:

The original list of strings looks like this

```
l_1 = ['09:13:34\t135\t94\t77\t2.97\t2.247\\\n', '09:14:34\t135\t94\t77\t3.03\t2.207\\\n', '09:15:34\t130\t94\t79\t2.83\t2.331\\\n', '09:16:34\t132\t95\t80\t2.86\t2.331\\\n
```

What I'd like is to strip the `\\\n` of the end of each string and then separate each string at the `\t`. So, for example, `l_1[0]` should end going from this

```
'09:13:34\t135\t94\t77\t2.97\t2.247\\\n'
```

to this:

```
l_2 = ['09:13:34', 135, 94, 97, 2.97, 2.247]
```

For context, l_1 is from a plain text file where each new line is a timestamped observation of biometric data, each text file is one participant and I need to combine all the lines into a single row in a pandas data frame, and may need to do this for 100-200 text files at a time. Obviously I'd like to be able to automate that.

What I've tried so far is:

```
import re

with open("data_1.txt") as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

i = contents[0]
re.split(r'\t+', i.rstrip('\\\n'))

print(i)
```

However, when I run that l_1 just becomes

```
<class 'list'>
[['', '}']]
```

So I have not moved onto storing the chunks in a new list and then making that list a row in a data frame.

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong (and how to do it right) I'd be much obliged.

Comment: You say you are doing it in pandas, do you mean to store all the field data in a single  column? This does not seem to make sense. Could you please clear out the expected format, the final result?

Comment: As I said in the question, I want each chunk to end up on a single continuous row so l_1[0] would be the first 6 cells on that row, l_1[1] would be the second 6 cells on that row and so on. I apologise if that doesn't make sense in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

with open("filename",'r') as dataload:

```
for i in dataload.readlines():

    print(str(i.split('\\t')[0:-1]).replace('\'',''))
```

Output-

["09:13:34", 135, 94, 77, 2.97]

["09:14:34", 135, 94, 77, 3.03]

["09:15:34", 130, 94, 79, 2.83]

["09:16:34", 132, 95, 80, 2.86]

Comment: str(i.split('\\t')[0:-1]).replace('\'','').replace('\"','\''))  for ['09:13:34', 135, 94, 77, 2.97]

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to change it to ```print(str(i.split('\t')[0:-1]).replace('\'',''))``` but once I did it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have added two examples below. Please do check them out. I have set them to be read at 32 bytes at a time. But you can increase, decrease or go crazy and have fun with it.

**Normal way:**

```
blocks = []
while True:
    block = f.read(32)
    if block == '':
        break
    blocks.append(block)
```

**Pythonic Way(One of the most efficient way):**

```
blocks = []
for block in iter(partial(f.read,32),''):
    blocks.append(block)
```

Have a great day sir.

Comment: The reason we do not compare a None type here:
    if block == '':
is because None is used in most codes and they tend to have it in their files as well in the place of Nulls or voids. Hence we compare with empty quotations at the end.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer sir. I'll play around with this as an option.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly using Python `split()` and `strip()`:

```
l_1 = [
  '09:13:34\t135\t94\t77\t2.97\t2.247\\\n', 
  '09:14:34\t135\t94\t77\t3.03\t2.207\\\n', 
  '09:15:34\t130\t94\t79\t2.83\t2.331\\\n', 
  '09:16:34\t132\t95\t80\t2.86\t2.331\\\n']

l_2 = [line.strip("\\\n") for line in l_1]
l_3 = [line.split("\t") for line in l_2]
```

Output for `l_3` is :

```
[
  ['09:13:34', '135', '94', '77', '2.97', '2.247'],
  ['09:14:34', '135', '94', '77', '3.03', '2.207'],
  ['09:15:34', '130', '94', '79', '2.83', '2.331'],
  ['09:16:34', '132', '95', '80', '2.86', '2.331']
]
```

Comment: If the file never contains a new line or a tab section, then your code will not work.
What if its a stream of bytes of a video without a line or a tab.

Comment: OP question is about striping and splitting a specific line because his data is formatted as stated in the question: `09:13:34\t135\t94\t77\t2.97\t2.247\\\n`. This line always contains tabs and a return.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```py
>>> [re.split(r'\t', x.rstrip('\\\n')) for x in l_1]
[['09:13:34', '135', '94', '77', '2.97', '2.247'], ['09:14:34', '135', '94', '77', '3.03', '2.207'], ['09:15:34', '130', '94', '79', '2.83', '2.331'], ['09:16:34', '132', '95', '80', '2.86', '2.331']]
```

Comment: If the file never contains a new line or a tab section, then your code will not work.
What if its a stream of bytes of a video without a line or a tab.

Comment: I see what you're saying here @High-Octane, but for the exact purpose I asked this is a good answer.